# Strange looping audio in mobile browsers for NodeJS application

Tags: ios, html, node.js, google-chrome, express

To illustrate the problem I'm having I created a sample set of code in the Express framework for NodeJS. When a user goes to http://example.com/ there's supposed to be an audio element ready to play the contents of music.mp3. The problem I've noticed on mobile browsers, specifically iOS Chrome and Safari, is that if "music.mp3" is long enough, the entirety of the file won't play, it'll just loop back to the beginning after a while. Any tips/explanations that could explain this behavior to me?

```
var fs = require("fs");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get("/music.mp3", function (req, res) {
    var music = fs.createReadStream("./music.mp3");
    music.pipe(res);
});

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.send("<audio controls><source src=\"music.mp3\">Your browser sucks</audio>");
});

app.listen(8080);
```